# Rewriting function with recursive self-calls so that RangeError Maximum call stack size is resolved

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a function that calls itself and I don't see any potential infinite-loops and I am only running the loop if the counter is less than the length of an array.

Does anyone have any idea why the call stack size is throwing an error?

```
function train(i, data, n, nTwo, func){
        if(i===data.length && nTwo!==undefined) done();
        else if(netTwo===undefined) func();
        else (new Trainer(n)).workerTrain([data[i]], train(i++,     trainingSet, l, y));
    }
    train(0, trainingSet, l, y);
```

I can't run this inside a for-loop as I can initiate a worker until the previous one is done. Or at least when I tried to, I got an error.
So I'm running the next worker in the previous worker's callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the post-increment operator (`i++`), which returns the current value **before** incrementing the variable. In other words, you  always call you function with the same `i`.

Using the pre-incremenet (`++i`) instead should solve the issue:

```
else (new Trainer(n)).workerTrain([data[i]], train(++i, trainingSet, l, y));
```

Comment: I've seen many people use pre-increments. Which is more proper?

Comment: @wordSmith Both pre-incrementing and post-incrementing are fine, you just need to use each one in the proper context (here, for example, using post-increment didn't do what you meant to do).

Answer (score 0):

netTwo is not defined.  nTwo is a parameter in the function and used in the first if clause.  But the else if clause has an undefined variable named "netTwo."  I therefore would expect a problem.